# Dynamic CSS value

Tags: jquery, css, owasp

We have lot of inline styles being used in our application.
I am working to get rid of them as they are prone to XSS attacks.
Though I have been able to replace most of these with CSS classes ,there are few like below which are setting style values dynamically based on the value of the  var= backgroundColor

```
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${order.isDisabled()}">
                        <c:set var="backgroundColor" value="#f0f0f0"/>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:when test="${empty order.isConfirmed}">
                        <c:set var="backgroundColor" value="transparent"/>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <c:set var="backgroundColor">${record.statusBGColor}</c:set>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>

                <reg class="reg">
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:${backgroundColor};"></rect>
                </reg>
            </div>
```

Is there any way to create a css class which takes a value(${backgroundColor) dynamically or some other way by which I can remove inline style ?

We are using jquery in our application

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to remove inline fill style for your `rect`, you could do it in js like this:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("rect");
for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++)
{
   element[i].style.removeProperty('fill');
  }
```

Or if you want to remove all inline styles using jquery, this is a helpful command:

```
$('rect').removeAttr('style');
```

Or if you really want to nuke all inline styles on everything there's this:

```
$('*').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: I want to replace inline styles with something equivalent so that end customer experience remains safe

Comment: @Rips Why not add the style using jquery then? So for instance, something like this: `$("rect").css("fill", "yellow");`

Comment: This is not acceptable to CSP violations. Having looked around we can do this like below : ```document.querySelector('div').style.display = 'none';```